# How to get build number, build log url in buildbot?

Tags: buildbot

I am having buildbot master in one PC and slaves in other one. I need the buildbot build log url like (http://:8010/builders/xyz/builds/1) in slave PC for each build in an automated way.

Could someone help in getting the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need them from within the build or from an external source?

Comment: Anything is fine, but if it is within the build, that would be great :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use build properties:

```
self.getProperty("buildnumber")
```

or, if you need to include it in a command:

```
d = WithProperties('%s','buildnumber')
command = ['echo', d]
```

Then the url will be: BUILDBOT_URL/xyz/builds/BUILD_NUMBER

Comment: @hitwen- One doubt, this modificatio whether i need to keep in master.cfg. Actually i am using shell scripts for build. So, can i use the same in shell script also.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, this pieces of code should be in your steps definitions in master.cfg or included files

Comment: Ok hithwen, got it now.. got confused with build steps. I will try and will get back to you. Thanks a lot!!